# Azure Logic App Upload Blob Trigger with Trigger Condition not fired

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App (Standard) which is in a VNET integrated environment.
I want to get triggered by an upload of a blob to a storage account with the following structure:

"containerName/SubFolder1/file.zrxp"

I need to use the Azure Blob Connector (in App)
[image]

I know that the connector gets only triggered if I choose as Blob Path the name of the container.
Therefore I need to be sure, that the Logic App is only triggered, by a specific type of files with the ending "*.zrxp".
So I wanted to use Trigger Conditions like this:

```
"triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_updated": {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "expression": "@endsWith(triggerBody()?['name'],'.zrxp')"
                    }
                ],
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "path": "containerName"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "AzureBlob-4",
                        "operationId": "whenABlobIsAddedOrModified",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ServiceProvider"
            }
        }
```

But if I upload a file with this file ending to this container (containerName/SubFolder1), the workflow is not tiggered.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: try adding **containerName/SubFolder1/{name}.zrxp** in blob path parameter like [image](https://i.imgur.com/VXo4KoY.png), It will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have reproduced the issue at my environment and got the expected result*

[image]

**`Code view:`**

```
{
"definition": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
"actions": {},
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"outputs": {},
"triggers": {
"When_a_blob_is_added_or_updated": {
"inputs": {
"parameters": {
"path": "demo-container/SubFolder1/{name}.zrxp"
},
"serviceProviderConfiguration": {
"connectionName": "AzureBlob-2",
"operationId": "whenABlobIsAddedOrModified",
"serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
}
},
"type": "ServiceProvider"
}
}
},
"kind": "Stateful"
}
```

**`Storage Account:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**Reference**:- [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=standard#tabpanel_1_standard)