# Has "conditions" property of Trigger actions been deprecated for Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to add a condition to a trigger in my Azure Logic App workflow so that I can wait to trigger until I get an event with a specific value. My trigger action looks like:

```
                "Event_Received": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "body": {
                            "properties": {
                                "destination": {
                                    "endpointType": "webhook",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                    }
                                },
                                "topic": "/subscriptions/<REDACTED>/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/MyDomain/topics/MyTopic"
                            }
                        },
                        "host": {
                            "connection": {
                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgrid']['connectionId']"
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "/subscriptions/<REDACTED>/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.EventGrid.Domains.Topics')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                        "queries": {
                            "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-15-preview"
                        }
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
                }
```

I want to add a condition to check if the event data contains a specific value, in this case let's say 'ABC'. So I read the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#trigger-conditions), and tried adding the conditions property to the action:

```
"conditions": [ {
  "expression": "@equals(triggerBody()?['name'], 'ABC')"
} ]
```

When I try to save this in Azure Code View I get an error that the `conditions` property has been deprecated since 2016. But I see similar questions where this appears to work, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913542/azure-logic-app-upload-blob-trigger-with-trigger-condition-not-fired) and the Microsoft docs are from 2023.

The only difference I can see is the question I linked to is using the property for the trigger that triggers the app while my trigger occurs after the app has started running.

Answer (score 0):

> Has "conditions" property of Trigger actions been deprecated for Azure Logic Apps?

You need to use below approach to make it work as expected:

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "expression": "@equals(triggerBody()?['name'], 'ABC')"
                    }
                ],
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

[image]

**`Design:`**

Or click on 3 dots then on settings:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`For resource event:`**

[image]

[image]